# PHPSpreadsheet to Read Passworded XLSX

Tags: php-7, xlsx, phpspreadsheet, spout

I've spent all day searching both the documentation and the web but there doesn't seem to be a way to programmatically open a passworded spreadsheet with phpspreadsheet; and spout library for that matter.

In Phpspreadsheet, I'm interested in the xlsx reader and have followed the inheritance chain to the root class but none have a "setpassword" type method (I notice writer class has though.)

Is this a true oversight in both libraries or have I missed something somehow? Is there any other way to do this in PHP? Or next best, strip the password off a set of xlsx files programmatically and then read it with either library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing no other solution, I solved this by writing VBA to open each file and save without the password. Then I could process with PHPSpreadsheet.